# I can't transfer files from PC (Ubuntu 22.04) to phone via cable

Tags: android, transfer, mtp

Please help
I tried connecting my android to my PC. It shows just fine. But when copying files from my PC to phone, it just doesn't work. Copying files from phone to PC works.
I use **Ubuntu 22.04** PC and **Infinix hot 12i (Android 11)**.
I tried installing gmtp

```
sudo apt-get install gmtp
```

It still didn't work. It seems to be some kind of permission problem.
I also tried wireless transfer method like **KDE connect**. But still the same problem.

> I can receive but can't send to phone

Comment: "your phone" looks like a USB disk to the computer. Check its status with `mount`. Does it have `ro` or `rw`? Read `man mount` and try remounting it with `sudo mount -o remount,rw ...`. In the past, was the phone connected to a Windows system with "Fast Boot" enabled?

Comment: Do you get any actual error messages?

Comment: Thanks @waltinator. It's solved now